# Is there any API to add tracking number and order status from my application to PayPal?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

Currently I add tracking number, order status, and shipping company manually using below steps :

Log in to my PayPal account, click "Overview" and then click "Payments Received" to bring up my account's recent activity.
Click the "Print Shipping Label" drop-down menu next to the payment to which I need to submit a tracking number and then select the "Add Tracking Info" option.
Enter the required information in the pop-up window that appears including the tracking number, carrier and shipment status. Click the "Save" button to finish submitting your tracking data to PayPal.

Now I want to automate add tracking information, order status and shipping company using my application.

Please suggest !

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-REST-API-issues/issues/158

Comment: Yes, they just added the support in their API.. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/tracking/v1/ I'm trying to get it to work with the paypal woocommerce plugin, no luck so far. https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-checkout/ I was trying to be able to choose a field to send over once status is complete.

Answer (score 0):

No, and [here's why](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/payments-shipping-fulfilment/t/putting-tracking-number-on-paypal-336098):

> ...So I actually called PayPal myself and they advised that the
>   "Tracking number box" on your merchant dashboard is usually only used
>   if you're using the PayPal Shipping Label area.
>
> https://www.paypal.com/ca/webapps/mpp/shipping-centre
>
> Meaning, general use for outside providers (like Shopify) is to not
>   hand off shipping information, since it's all being processed our side
>   (order con­firmation/notification) instead of on PayPal.
>   PayPal Express Checkout just being the money acceptance, not the
>   tracking/fulfillment/shipping for (most) businesses.